# Deciphering the geospatial structure of a particular NetCDF file

Tags: netcdf

I am trying to find the structure of the following NetCDF file: [latlon_idgrid_file.nc](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/5iywl3zmuwanepa72t8if/latlon_idgrid_file.nc?rlkey=9cx75o2eolkv4ln0eugesai5j&dl=0)

The mystery here for me is the *idgrid* variable which has a lon and lat index from 0 to 240 and 208 respectively with a step of 1. As values it has some irrelevant to the issue numbers. However it is somehow georeferenced with actual lon/lat coords, and as a result Panoply can see this and correctly plot it as Geo2D:

[image]

As a note, the nc file has two variables *lon* and *lat* which contain values of corresponding actual lon/lat coords for each of the corresponding numbers at the same 'lat'/'lon' indices.

To add here that the *idgrid* variable is defined by a (lon_index: 240, lat_index: 208) grid, when I inspect it as e.g. xarray. However, the actual lon/lat coords that Panoply sees are from the lon and lat variables which contain: Unique Lons from latlon_idgrid_file.nc: 22786, Unique Lats from latlon_idgrid_file.nc: 22774. How is this possible and how does it work?

How can I understand the underlying structure, the definitions, the geospatial information, CRS, etc included somehow to this product?

Answer (score 1):

The data are on what Panoply calls an auxiliary 2D grid. Optimally, the ldgrid variable should have a `coordinates` attribute specifying that the lon and lat variables provide the grid information, but Panoply (or the library it uses) is figuring things out anyway because those variables are reasonably easy to identify as longitude and latitude values even though their units attributes are not set well.

Take a look at the [CF convention for netCDF metadata](http://cfconventions.org), and specifically section 5.2 for discussion of this gridding scheme.

Given the shape of the gridded data, I suspect the original gridding is on a conic projection. But as its definition is not included in the file, Panoply is instead just using the specified Lon-lat values.

Comment: Thank you for the insights @R.Schmuck, however I have the following trouble understanding yet: The idgrid variable is defined by a (lon_index: 240, lat_index: 208) grid, when I inspect it as e.g. xarray. However, the actual lon/lat coords that Panoply sees are from the lon and lat variables which contain: Unique Lons from latlon_idgrid_file.nc: 22786, Unique Lats from latlon_idgrid_file.nc: 22774. How is this possible and how does it work?

Comment: Take a look at the "CDL" description of the dataset that Panoply shows in the info panel of its Sources window. What Panoply sees for the long and the lat coordinate variables are the same 240x208 dimensions that the ldgrid variable is defined on. So e.g. data point [m,n] on the ldgrid array is located at longitude [m,n] on the lon array and latitude [m,n] on the lat array.

Comment: Thanks again R.Schmunk, Ok I gathered that much since I inspected the data, but still, I am in confusion if it is a Panoply interpretation and visualization aspect that it manages to plot it correctly or if there is some other info I am missing.

Comment: The only trick to it is that the 240x208 grid of points provided by the lon and lat variables is not a neat Cartesian set of lon and lat points, so Panoply must figure out a way to regrid the data values onto a simple lon-lat grid. How it does so depends on whether you're making an interpolated or non-interpolated plot. Either way, there are no grid mapping formulae to do so because there is no information available in the dataset to tell it what map projection was originally used.

Comment: Another way of looking at it is that the lon and lat values in that dataset provide the points on a mesh, so to make a plot, you have to decide how to fill in the mesh.

Comment: Thanks once more for the inputs. While I am processing the whole thing, maybe you could share some thoughts on how to transform such a dataset to a more "regular" one?

Comment: It's just a matter of deciding on an interpolation scheme between the points on your regular grid and the nearest points on the dataset's input grid. A simple bilinear interpolation is likely good enough.

Comment: Thanks! The problem here is that e.g. CDO or ncview does not recognize the dataset characteristics, because it has no set coordinate system, it is just that Panoply sees the data "properly". For example, QGIS also does not recognize the link between the 'ancillary' coordinates that are linked and somehow figured out by Panoply. So, any clues how could I perform such as interpolation?